# Ignoring properties when serializing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, asp.net-mvc-futures

I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

I am trying to implement a multi-step wizard, and i'm using the `Html.Serialize` html helper in MVC3 Futures.  This works well, except one of the properties in my model is a `SelectList`.  I don't want this property serialized (and it blows up when it tries anyways).

I can't use `[NonSerialized]` because that only works on fields, not properties.  I've even tried some of the other normal ways such as `[XmlIgnore]` (which I didn't think would work anyways).

Can anyone suggest an attribute that will ignore a property in a model when using `Html.Serialize`?

EDIT:

The error I get when I try to serialize is a InvalidDataContractException.  There is this message:

> Type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

However, if I do this then I have to mark all the members with `[DataMember]` just to exclude 1 property, which seems kind of stupid.

UPDATE:

A quick example of this is this bit of code (make sure to add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll):

Test.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public SelectList TestList { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View(new Test() { ID = 0, TestList = new SelectList(new [] {""})});
}
```

Home/About.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Test 

@Html.Serialize("Test", Model)
```

This generates the InvalidDataContractException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public SelectList Items { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

or simply:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: [IgnoreDataMember] doesn't do anything either.  I still get the same Serialization error, probably because there's no [DataContract] on the class (that's my guess).  However, Adding DataContract means adding [DataMember] attributes, so I'm not sure what the purpose is.

Comment: Are you saying that the serializer ignores IEnumerables by default?

Comment: @MystereMan, the problem is with the `SelectList` class itself. It cannot be serialized. When you use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, the property is not ignored but it will serialize if the concrete type is for example `SelectListItem[]` or `List<SelectListItem>`. I have tested the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute and it worked for me with the `SelectList` type. Could you show a narrowed down version of your view model allowing to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MystereMan, remove the `[Serializable]` attribute from your Test class. Look at my answer. There is no such attribute on MyViewModel.

Comment: Doh! I had assumed you had left out the attribute.  I was under the impression that the [Serializable] attribute was required.

Comment: If I leave off the [Serializable] attibute, I get: "Assembly 'x' is not marked as serializable" when I try to serialize it.