# Ignore DateTime prop from being serialized (not working)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, javascriptserializer

i have tried the solution proposed in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285439/ignoring-properties-when-serializing) solution

i have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

when the JavaScriptSerializer serializes the result it changes the date time for example if i have `2012-07-20` in my database after the serialization it is returned as `2012-07-21` because the application is hosted at a location that is outside my time zone i am facing a lot of problems because of it

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`[ScriptIgnore]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) attribute to exclude properties from being serialized with the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    ... some other properties
}
```

This being said, the correct way to do this is to use a view model that simply won't contain the property that you don't want to be contained in the response and then return this view model instead of *torturing* your domain models with plumbing code about serialization which they should be absolutely agnostic of.

Comment: thanks Darin for replying, i'm already using viewmodel and i need to display the date thats y it was included in the model, also i have tried the `[ScriptIgnore]' option when i do that i think i exclude the prop form the resulting json produced. why iam trying to ignore the datetime property is i am suspecting that when it is serialized it changes my date to some utc format that adds an offset of 1 day in my current date...

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Please provide a full example (Model, Controller, View) illustrating your problem. Ideally hardcode values so that I don't need to create a database or something in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: its difficult to cut out the relavant code, let me explain the problem, i am in the GMT +5 zone, i have hosted my application in USA that is in different time zone, i have handled the datetime conversion in my code but the problem is when i serialize the result that contains the datetime the serializer converts it in the UTC time stamp, the actual date in the database is '2012-07-20' but when i convert it into json using `JavaScriptSerializer` it converts it into utc time stamp which becomes equivalent to something like `1342869568` i tried converting  my time to utc, no efect

Comment: ... so when in my view i deserialize json in the view it gives me `2012-07-21`